# How to change php configuration directory of php.ini file on a subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

I have a FTP access to subdomain.website.com and not to the cPanel of website.com
I want to change some settings on php.ini file, but I am unable to find one. And the php info says

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/lib

Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit /usr/local/lib/php.ini. This is a global PHP configuration file on cPanel server.

Depending on your host server's configuration, you can upload your custom php.ini inside your subdomain's document root. If your host does not allow custom php.ini, you can try .htaccess file to change PHP settings using php_value flag.

Changing default PHP configuration parameters is totally depend on the host server's configuration.

Edit:

If your host server is configured to update PHP configuration value via .htaccess, add following line in your .htaccess:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

If server is not configured to allow php_value flag, your website will stop working. In that case, you need to remove this code from your .htaccess and you will need to contact your host to ask them proper way to use custom php settings.

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess file on my website. I tried to create a new file, and put the command for the max execution time, and after that none of my website's page was accessible. I had to delete .htaccess file via FTP.
How to make a .htaccess file and what to put into it? I was to increase the max_execution_time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the document root of the sub-domain only, then you will not be able to access this file. The reason for this is that the directory in which `php.ini` resides is *above* the directory you have access to.

This would also be the case when using shared hosting - most hosting providers do not allow you to touch this file.

You could, however, make in-memory changes to the configuration using an `.htaccess` file that resides in the document root of your sub-domain. You can do this with the `php_value` directive. This can only be done when using PHP as an Apache module - if PHP is running in CGI mode, then this is not possible.

For more information, please consult the PHP Manual: [How to change configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)